# How can i do a user IP check in here?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I really need you kind help here, can someone be kind enough to show me how can i do a Ip check in the following codes? as of now it checks username and password thats ok but i wish to assign IP of users assigned to their tables so while doing a login check it also checks whether the users current ip matches with the one stored in database?

its not like i haven't tried, I have been trying but not getting any output after adding the IP field it stops logging me in

here is my form section from login.php

```
<p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value=""  placeholder="Username" required /></p> 
    <p><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value=""  placeholder="Your Password" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="IP" value="<?php echo get_client_ip(); ?>" readonly/></p>
```

here is the login.php validation

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;
    
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}
```

and here is the user.php codes i guess this is where the ip needs to be checked?

```
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, IP FROM members WHERE username = :username AND IP = :IP ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username, 'IP ' => $ip));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the password.php codes

```
if (!defined('PASSWORD_DEFAULT')) {
        define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);
        define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}

    Class Password {

        public function __construct() {}

        function password_hash($password, $algo, array $options = array()) {
            if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
                trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_hash to function", E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
            }
            if (!is_string($password)) {
                trigger_error("password_hash(): Password must be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
            }
            if (!is_int($algo)) {
                trigger_error("password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, " . gettype($algo) . " given", E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
            }
            switch ($algo) {
                case PASSWORD_BCRYPT :
                    // Note that this is a C constant, but not exposed to PHP, so we don't define it here.
                    $cost = 10;
                    if (isset($options['cost'])) {
                        $cost = $options['cost'];
                        if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
                            trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: %d", $cost), E_USER_WARNING);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    // The length of salt to generate
                    $raw_salt_len = 16;
                    // The length required in the final serialization
                    $required_salt_len = 22;
                    $hash_format = sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);
                    break;
                default :
                    trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Unknown password hashing algorithm: %s", $algo), E_USER_WARNING);
                    return null;
            }
            if (isset($options['salt'])) {
                switch (gettype($options['salt'])) {
                    case 'NULL' :
                    case 'boolean' :
                    case 'integer' :
                    case 'double' :
                    case 'string' :
                        $salt = (string)$options['salt'];
                        break;
                    case 'object' :
                        if (method_exists($options['salt'], '__tostring')) {
                            $salt = (string)$options['salt'];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 'array' :
                    case 'resource' :
                    default :
                        trigger_error('password_hash(): Non-string salt parameter supplied', E_USER_WARNING);
                        return null;
                }
                if (strlen($salt) < $required_salt_len) {
                    trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: %d expecting %d", strlen($salt), $required_salt_len), E_USER_WARNING);
                    return null;
                } elseif (0 == preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$#D', $salt)) {
                    $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt));
                }
            } else {
                $buffer = '';
                $buffer_valid = false;
                if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') && !defined('PHALANGER')) {
                    $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
                    if ($buffer) {
                        $buffer_valid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!$buffer_valid && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
                    $buffer = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($raw_salt_len);
                    if ($buffer) {
                        $buffer_valid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!$buffer_valid && is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
                    $f = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
                    $read = strlen($buffer);
                    while ($read < $raw_salt_len) {
                        $buffer .= fread($f, $raw_salt_len - $read);
                        $read = strlen($buffer);
                    }
                    fclose($f);
                    if ($read >= $raw_salt_len) {
                        $buffer_valid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!$buffer_valid || strlen($buffer) < $raw_salt_len) {
                    $bl = strlen($buffer);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $raw_salt_len; $i++) {
                        if ($i < $bl) {
                            $buffer[$i] = $buffer[$i] ^ chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                        } else {
                            $buffer .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                        }
                    }
                }
                $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($buffer));
            }
            $salt = substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);

            $hash = $hash_format . $salt;

            $ret = crypt($password, $hash);

            if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
                return false;
            }

            return $ret;
        }

       
        function password_get_info($hash) {
            $return = array('algo' => 0, 'algoName' => 'unknown', 'options' => array(), );
            if (substr($hash, 0, 4) == '$2y$' && strlen($hash) == 60) {
                $return['algo'] = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
                $return['algoName'] = 'bcrypt';
                list($cost) = sscanf($hash, "$2y$%d$");
                $return['options']['cost'] = $cost;
            }
            return $return;
        }

       
        function password_needs_rehash($hash, $algo, array $options = array()) {
            $info = password_get_info($hash);
            if ($info['algo'] != $algo) {
                return true;
            }
            switch ($algo) {
                case PASSWORD_BCRYPT :
                    $cost = isset($options['cost']) ? $options['cost'] : 10;
                    if ($cost != $info['options']['cost']) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

       
        public function password_verify($password, $hash) {
            if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
                trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
            $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
            if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) != strlen($hash) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
                return false;
            }

            $status = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ret); $i++) {
                $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
            }

            return $status === 0;
        }

    }
```

Really hoping someone you experts could help me out in here, will be really greatful.

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: What happens if the IP address doesn't match? Do you refuse to log someone in? That could render your  system unusable since the IP address is rarely under the control of the user, and can change from one session to the next, depending on the way the system is being used. Think of mobile devices moving between WiFi networks, or short life DHCP allocations from one day to the next. Think carefully here. This is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: its not doing any Ip check i cannot seem to understand why

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular yes i am aware of all that its just an experiment am doing but stuck with the IP check part

Comment: 90% of thus code is probably irrelevant, reduce it down to a [mre] of where you try to check the user's IP and use the result. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php for basics of how to get the IP address